# getting error: module 'pdfkit' has no attribute 'configuration'

Tags: python, windows, wkhtmltopdf

When I want to replace the html file with a pdf, I get an error when I click run: module 'pdfkit' has no attribute 'configuration'

```
import pdfkit

path_wkhtmltopdf = 'C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)

options = {
    'zoom': 1.00,
    'page-size':'A3',
    'encoding':'utf-8', 
    'margin-top':'0cm',
    'margin-bottom':'0cm',
    'margin-left':'0cm',
    'margin-right':'0cm'
}


pdfkit.from_file(report.html,report.pdf,configuration=config,options=options)
```

Comment: when I run the code without running earlier, i.e. I run it in the console it works

Comment: path_wkhtmltopdf is a directory path not exe/file

Comment: this is only the name of the variable, if I am not mistaken and should not matter. As I said, the code works, but only in the console itself.